# How to convert java.util.List[java.lang.Double] to Scala's List[Double]?

Tags: java, scala, implicit-conversion

I'd like to convert a Java list of Java doubles (java.util.List[java.lang.Double]) to a Scala list of Scala doubles (List[Double]) in an efficient way.

Currently I'm mapping over the list converting each Double value to a Scala Double. I'd prefer not to map over every value and am looking for a more efficient way of doing this.

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.mutable.Buffer

val j: java.util.List[java.lang.Double] = Buffer(new java.lang.Double(1.0), new java.lang.Double(2.0))
val s: List[Double] = ...
```

I've seen documentation to go from Scala --> Java, but not much going the other way.

Comment: "I've seen documentation to go from Scala --> Java, but not much going the other way."... did you now? Care to share that information? ;-)

Comment: I found out the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46830217/4533188

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The recommendation is to use `JavaConverters`, not `JavaConversions`:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.breakOut
val l: List[Double] = j.asScala.map(_.doubleValue)(breakOut)
```

`doubleValue` will convert it from a `java.lang.Double` into a `scala.Double`.  `breakOut` tells it to produce a `List` as the result of the `map`, without having to traverse it another time to convert to a `List`.  You could also just do `toList` instead of `breakOut` if you didn't care about the extra traversal.

The Java classes are entirely different objects from the Scala ones; it's not just a name-change. Thus, it would be impossible to convert without traversing. You have to create an entirely new collection and then look at each element in order to (convert it and) move it over.

The reason the types are different is that java.lang.Double is a "boxed primitive" whereas scala.Double is equivalent to Java's double primitive. The conversion here is essentially "unboxing" the primitive.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without any traversals? Perhaps that's not possible, but I naively imagine that casting won't involve any traversals.

Comment: Note that if you are willing to accept a `Seq` rather than a `List` precisely, you can avoid the traversal by converting the Scala-converted Java `List` into a view by calling the `view` method before calling `map`. That will give you a lazily evaluated `SeqView` that will apply the conversions to the elements on an as-needed basis.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

val javaList : java.util.List[Double] = ...
val scalaList : List[Double] = j.asScala.toList
```

Comment: This is able to cast a java.util.list[Double] to a List[Double], but the tricky part is also converting from java.lang.Double to Scala Double.

Comment: @Erik, It's not a cast: `asScala` traverses the java-based collection and builds a brand new scala-based collection.  It has to since the classes are completely different.

Comment: @dhg, you're in fact wrong. `asScala` does not traverse a collection; `asScala` creates a *view* into the original collection. It's `toList` which performs actual traversal. See `scala.collection.convert.Wrappers` trait: it contains implementations of these views, and it is obvious that they only forward collection operations to the original Java collections.

Comment: @dhg, you're right, however, that `javaList.asScala.map(_.doubleValue).toList` will perform two traversals, the first one happening in `map`, and the second in `toList`.