# How to convert Scala's List[Double] to java.util.List[java.lang.Double]?

Tags: java, scala, collections

I have only seen examples where the result is a Java list of Scala doubles. I got as far as

```
def getDistance(): java.util.List[java.lang.Double] = {
  val javadistance = distance.toList.asJava
  javadistance
}
```

but this is still a Java list containing Scala doubles (`distance` is a member of the same class as `getDistance`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One has to use the java boxed variant in a map:

```
  def getDistance(): java.util.List[java.lang.Double] = {
    distance.toList.map(Double.box).asJava
  }
```

Comment: FYI: This does not work in Scala 2.12, it's added in Scala 2.13

Answer (score 1):

Other than Scala 2.13+ `box` method, you can use:

```
def getDistance(): java.util.List[java.lang.Double] = {
  val javadistance = distance.toList.map(java.lang.Double.valueOf).asJava
  javadistance
}
```